# How to get TalkBack to read into nested RecyclerView's contents

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, talkback

I have a RecyclerView, whose cells each contain a complex layout of various Elements such as images, text fields, etc.  One of the elements contained within the main RecyclerView's cells is another RecyclerView (it's a grid list of "chips").

When I have TalkBack turned on, tapping on a cell in my main recycler, TalkBack proceeds to read all of the elements within that selected cell except one, that chips recycler view.

**The problem I'm having is, it skips the chips RecyclerView altogether.**  I need it to read the text in each one of the chips before moving on to the next element in the cell.

I've tried just about everything I can think of or have found.  I have a feeling there's an outside-the-box answer to this I'm unaware of.  Please help.  Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    tools:background="@drawable/things_and_stuff"
    tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_that_works"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/next_item"
        tools:text="Tools Text" />

<!--  Several items skipped for simplification and obfuscation.  -->

<!--  This recycler contains any number of "Chips", which is essentially a text view.
I can make it read if I set it up as an assertive header, but then it reads at the wrong time.  -->
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/why_does_this_get_skipped"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/another_item"
        tools:itemCount="1"
        tools:listitem="@layout/another_layout" />

</merge>
```